# How to set active to the class

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I am changing the language by changeCulture method which is ;

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(Culture lang, string returnUrl)
{
    if (returnUrl.Length >= 3) returnUrl = returnUrl.Substring(3);
    return Redirect("/" + lang.ToString() + returnUrl);
}
```

and here is the html part ;

```
 <li class="currency-EUR">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = (int)SkycapGaming.Culture.Tr, returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })">TR</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="TR">
</li>
<li class="currency-USD">
    <a href="@Url.Action("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = (int)SkycapGaming.Culture.En, returnUrl = this.Request.RawUrl })">EN</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="EN">
</li>
```

I want to set active to `<li class="currency-EUR">` When the page is on  so it should be `<li class="currency-EUR active">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing the language in url you could extract it and then just use javascript like

```
var url = window.location.href; //this return full url: http://webiste.com/eur/something.html
url = url.split("/");
url = url[1];
if(url == "eur"){
   $(".currency-EUR").addClass("active");
   $(".currency-USD").removeClass("active"); // in case it was already set
}else{
  $(".currency-USD").addClass("active");
  $(".currency-EUR").removeClass("active");
}
```

Comment: How can I change the span text with this method ?

Comment: @Jackal you could specify and id or class to a span and than use something like  $("#yourID").append("Some text"); if you are trying to add the text or if you are trying to add a class the same way as described above

Comment: well it didint work or sth wrong. I've added to here ;  $(".currency-USD").addClass("active");
        $(".currency-EUR").removeClass("active");
        $("#LanSpan").append("EN");

Comment: and in anycase always USD active even if I change to TR

Comment: @Jackal what didn't work ? Can you be a little bit more specific ?